# String Template literal type composed from Union of String Literals

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typeliteral

##### Given:

```
type State = 
  | 'read'
  | 'rejected'
  | 'sent'
  | 'refused'
  | 'expired' 
  | 'draft'
```

##### Needed:

the template literal type `Filters`, which defines a string of this kind: `darft,sent,refused`.

```
type Filters = 
  | `${State}`
  | `${State},${State}`
  | `${State},${State},${State}`
// ...
// allowing strings containing from 1 to all of the `State`s.
```

Comment: No repeats like `draft,draft`, right?  Will `State` always and forever have only 6 members?  You can indeed represent a `CommaSeparated<T>` type function that comes up with every permutation of at least one element of members of `T` separated by commas, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxDBZm)... but that operation is *combinatorially explosive*; for a `T` with  elements, `CommaSeparated<T>` has around ×!, for 6 elements that's 1,956 members, and TypeScript can handle that.  But for 9 elements that's 986,409 members, and TS will complain.

Comment: Please see the answer to the linked questions for more information... one answer says how to generate the huge union, while the other says how to make a generic type *constraint* instead, which is appropriate when the huge union would be too big to represent in TypeScript.